# Match string of all uppercase that can be 1 or more words has and has at least 2 spaces of white space before it

Tags: regex

I need to parse out names out from a PDF file. The names are always all uppercase and could be 1 or more words, i.e. `CHUBBY BOY` or `MIKE`. They are also indented so there are spaces before the names.

```
preg_match('/(?=[A-Z]{2,})([A-Z]+)/', $removedStar, $mymatches)
```

is getting pretty close.

```
if ( preg_match('/(?=[A-Z]{2,})([A-Z]+)/', $removedStar, $mymatches)) {
    $name_value = $removedStar;
    $nameValues[$nameCount] = $mymatches[0];
    $nameCount++;
}
```

These lines are the output of $removedStar

EXT. HOME FOR INSANE - PARKING LOT - SAME

12  12

A OLD DATSUN is BLASTING hard rock on shitty speakers-

the same song- Enjoyed!

YOUNG TEENS: a Drunk, a Jock, and a Chubby boy,

headbanging and drunk in the parking lot-

CHUBBY BOY

Shh quiet!  Listen-

5.

THEY HEAR THE SCREAM IN THE DISTANCE.  THEY GET QUIET- the

Drunk kid holding a beer GIGGLES-

DRUNK KID

Trippy.

this is actually getting even closer

```
strtoupper($removedStar) == $removedStar
```

Comment: this will return the single word names.    if(ctype_upper($removedStar)) {
    
    $name_value = $removedStar;
    $nameValues[$nameCount] = $name_value;
    $nameCount++;
   }

Comment: Maybe all you need is `preg_match_all('~\b\p{Lu}{2,}(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)*~u', $text, $mymatches)`? `print_r($mymatches[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
(?:  )([A-Z]+[A-Z ]*[A-Z])
```

- Two groups, the first is two spaces, but not captured
- At least one capital letter
- Followed by as many other capitals or spaces
- Ending in a capital

https://regexr.com/4n4u6

It won't match single characters, but it sounds like you don't need that.